# Apache tomcat stop

Tags: apache, tomcat

In Apache you can configure that operation will be load using the load_on_startup tag.
I want also when stopping Apache to do several operation using the stop tomcat command.
Is there something like that ?

10x

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is "Finalising a servlet"

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnags.html

```
Notifying Methods to Shut Down

To ensure a clean shutdown, your destroy method should not release any shared resources until all the service requests have completed. One part of doing this is to check the service counter. Another part is to notify the long-running methods that it is time to shut down. For this notification, another field is required. The field should have the usual access methods:

public class ShutdownExample extends HttpServlet {
    private boolean shuttingDown;
    ...
    //Access methods for shuttingDown
    protected synchronized void setShuttingDown(boolean flag) {
        shuttingDown = flag;
    }
    protected synchronized boolean isShuttingDown() {
        return shuttingDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the shutdown accures not as http request, but as shut down to the tomcat.

Comment: That's what your original question asked for. There is obviously some misunderstanding somewhere between us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code to handle Tomcat specific things, use a [LifecycleListener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html), i.e. create a class that implements LifecycleListener.

If you want to to things when your application starts, use a ServletListener.